# Font-awesome icons rendered like empty square

Tags: webpack, font-awesome

Here like i import font-awesome to my main.scss

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
```

I used webpack, and everything build correctly, probably, but for some reason icons are not rendered. [image]

**Edit 1:**

After i implemented my solution icons started rendering, but only when i starts `webpack-dev-server` [image]

But icons still not rendering if i build dist folder

[image]

Errors in the console:

[image]

I guess somethins wrong with my [webpack.config.js](https://hastebin.com/wacudukoce.js) cause after building process i have `/fonts` folder inside my `dist`
[image]

Comment: Did you misspell fontawesome in your example?  I see fortawesome.

Comment: @RufusVS nope. I used fa fa-search

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you need all of these .scss to be imported

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular'; 
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```